# In Java, what advantages do arrays have over Arraylists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The book I'm learning Java with said this of Arraylists:

"An ArrayList shrinks and grows as needed in a program, whereas an array has
a fixed length that is set when the array is created.

In an ArrayList list, the last slot is always list.size()-1, whereas in a partially
filled array, you, the programmer,must keep track of the last slot currently
in use.

For an ArrayList, you can do insertion or deletion with just a single statement.
Any shifting of elements is handled automatically. In an array, however, insertion
or deletion requires you to write the code that shifts the elements."

Arrays, meanwhile, have none of these things. I can't currently think of any reason to use arrays instead of Arraylists. Do methods arrays run faster than Arraylist methods? Do they use less memory than Arraylists somehow?

Comment: Arrays are fast, ArrayList is flexible/dynamic. Most people prefer using collections over arrays as the latter can usually end up making a lot more work for the developer.

Comment: there is at least one reason to use arrays: to be able to build a arraylist class

Answer (score 1):

- Arrays have nicer built-in syntax; you can just use `[]` instead of `.get` and `.set`.
- Arrays work properly with primitives without boxing overhead; e.g. you can have an `int[]` but not an `ArrayList<int>`.
- Arrays are slightly faster, yes.  Not by much, though, since `ArrayList` is only a very thin layer over an internal array.

Generally speaking, I would rarely use arrays other than with primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Do methods arrays run faster than Arraylist methods? Do they use less memory than Arraylists somehow?

That's it
I you just need to iterate over a inmutable data just do it with an array, but if you want to insert, delete, pop etc .. do it with a List